# why is my anova not working within shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shinyapp and I would like to display a boxplot and an anova table based on selections from the user.
At the moment my selectInput is working and I am getting the boxplots drawn, but I am getting an error with my anova. I have added a few print messages to help with debugging and maybe it has to do with the reactive variables .

The first time it prints I have an empty otu variable and therefore my data table dfM.sub is empty.

Any help is appreciated.

here is some sample data:

```
> dput(f_genus[,1:10])
structure(list(Acaulospora = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.26747086299941e-05, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000120048019207683, 0, 0, 0.000766283524904215, 
0.000207569362762056, 0, 0, 6.24375624375624e-05, 0, 0, 0.000163478829491581, 
0, 8.6884747382597e-05, 0.000185431282257317), Acaulosporaceae_unclassified = c(1.833415837046e-05, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2.23338916806253e-05, 2.26747086299941e-05, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Acremonium = c(0.00060502722622518, 
0.000363538956069187, 0.000367167850782985, 0.000292958736761927, 
0.000361125862984599, 0.000781686208821887, 0.000453494172599882, 
0.00042863266180883, 0.000702540856096215, 0.000124340992738486, 
0.000492340320778655, 0.00226802090523617, 0.00260104041616647, 
0.00295825967747754, 0.00592563133823822, 0.00322645694696511, 
0.00294056597246246, 0.000659568453783096, 0.00360192642357036, 
0.00118631368631369, 0.00338657501010918, 0.00288747723335258, 
0.00245218244237371, 0.00536866754240676, 0.00364915939006907, 
0.00361591000401768), Acrocalymma = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 4.24853956452469e-05, 
0, 4.53494172599882e-05, 0, 0, 0, 3.78723323675889e-05, 0, 0.00040016006402561, 
0.000252534362711498, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000187312687312687, 0, 
0.000888454533339256, 0.000122609122118686, 0.000456907875949512, 
0, 0.000494483419352845), Agaricales_unclassified = c(0, 0, 1.83583925391493e-05, 
0.000190423178895253, 8.49707912904939e-05, 2.23338916806253e-05, 
0.000408144755339894, 0.000782720512868298, 0.000351270428048107, 
0.000522232169501641, 0.000473404154594861, 0.0141997830588699, 
0.0251300520208083, 0.0215375735055377, 0.0124080334062438, 0.00786448880822747, 
0.0132498443229779, 0.0143220578535758, 0.00882269618357683, 
0.00705544455544456, 0.0143044884755358, 0.00266536360001777, 
0.00470001634788295, 0.0275858130104518, 0.0296711412311569, 
0.0323886639676113), Agaricomycetes_unclassified = c(5.500247511138e-05, 
1.91336292667993e-05, 3.67167850782985e-05, 5.85917473523854e-05, 
0.000106213489113117, 0.000111669458403127, 0.000113373543149971, 
0.000969082539741702, 0, 4.97363970953944e-05, 1.89361661837944e-05, 
0.0132136870131151, 0.0112444977991196, 0.00999314549586926, 
0.00914694770332074, 0.0140350877192982, 0.0126963260222791, 
0.012060680297748, 0.00392569509085758, 0.00842907092907093, 
0.0253740396279822, 0.00946204078006308, 0.0042504495667811, 
0.0116511508367125, 0.00886224423302489, 0.00750996693142133), 
    Agrocybe = c(0, 0, 0.000128508747774045, 0, 0.00424853956452469, 
    0.0017643774427694, 0, 0.000223634432248085, 5.01814897211582e-05, 
    0.00131801452302795, 0, 0, 0, 3.60763375302139e-05, 0, 0.0014519056261343, 
    0, 0, 0.0226233356266947, 0.000187312687312687, 0.00161746866154468, 
    0.00186575452001244, 0.00122609122118686, 0, 0, 0), Alatospora = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.000285567422468445, 0.000173769494765194, 0.000154526068547764
    ), Alternaria = c(0.00022000990044552, 0.000401806214602786, 
    0.0012667290852013, 0.000893524147123878, 0.000191184280403611, 
    0.000402010050251256, 0.000294771212189923, 0.000242270634935426, 
    0.000150544469163475, 0.000223813786929275, 0.00160957412562253, 
    0.00157775367320777, 0.000640256102440976, 0.00194812222663155, 
    0.00039769337840525, 0.00221818915103852, 0.00214488341520792, 
    0.00179025723169698, 0.00165931441984702, 0.00224775224775225, 
    0.00409421754953498, 0.00151037270667674, 0.00114435180644107, 
    0.000628248329430579, 0.000738520352752074, 0.00135982940322032
    ), Amphisphaeriaceae_unclassified = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000240096038415366, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000912289847517268, 0.000649009487900609)), .Names = c("Acaulospora", 
"Acaulosporaceae_unclassified", "Acremonium", "Acrocalymma", 
"Agaricales_unclassified", "Agaricomycetes_unclassified", "Agrocybe", 
"Alatospora", "Alternaria", "Amphisphaeriaceae_unclassified"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("R-B1", 
"R-B2", "R-B3", "R-BF-1", "R-BF-2", "R-BF-3", "R-BFi-1", "R-BFi-2", 
"R-Bi-1", "R-Bi-2", "R-Bi-3", "S-B1", "S-B2", "S-B3", "S-Bi-1", 
"S-Bi-2", "S-Bi-3", "S-BF-1", "S-BF-2", "S-BF-3", "S-BFi-1", 
"S-BFi-2", "S-BFi-3", "S1", "S2", "S3"))
```

and the metadata:

```
> dput(sample_metadata)
structure(list(Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Root", "Soil"), class = "factor"), 
    Bean = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("Bean", "No bean"), class = "factor"), 
    Fungi = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("Fungi", "NF"), class = "factor"), Insect = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Insect", 
    "NI"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Location", "Bean", 
"Fungi", "Insect"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("R-B1", 
"R-B2", "R-B3", "R-BF-1", "R-BF-2", "R-BF-3", "R-BFi-1", "R-BFi-2", 
"R-BFi-3", "R-Bi-1", "R-Bi-2", "R-Bi-3", "S-B1", "S-B2", "S-B3", 
"S-BF-1", "S-BF-2", "S-BF-3", "S-BFi-1", "S-BFi-2", "S-BFi-3", 
"S-Bi-1", "S-Bi-2", "S-Bi-3", "S1", "S2", "S3"))
```

heres the errors:

```
 Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7179
Warning in is.na(e2) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
Warning: Error in : Faceting variables must have at least one value
Stack trace (innermost first):
    111: combine_vars
    110: plyr::unrowname
    109: f
    108: self$compute_layout
    107: f
    106: self$facet$train
    105: f
    104: layout$setup
    103: ggplot2::ggplot_build
    102: print.ggplot
    101: print
     90: <reactive:plotObj>
     79: plotObj
     78: origRenderFunc
     77: output$plot
      1: runApp
[1] "otu selected: "

    Warning in is.na(e2) :
      is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
    [1] "dim dfM.sub:  0" "dim dfM.sub:  6"
    Warning: Error in contrasts<-: contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
    Stack trace (innermost first):
        87: contrasts<-
        86: model.matrix.default
        85: model.matrix
        84: stats::lm
        83: eval
        82: eval
        81: aov
        80: renderTable [/..../shiny/app.R#137]
        79: func
        78: origRenderFunc
        77: output$table
         1: runApp
    [1] "otu selected: Metarhizium"
    [1] "dim dfM.sub:  23" "dim dfM.sub:  6"
```

As you can see dfM.sub has 2 levels for all the factors>

```
> str(dfM.sub)
'data.frame':   26 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Location: Factor w/ 2 levels "Root","Soil": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Bean    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Bean","No bean": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Fungi   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Metarhizium",..: 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Insect  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Insect","NI": 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 384 levels "Acaulospora",..: 169 169 169 169 169 169 169 169 169 169 ...
 $ abund   : num  0.00548 0.00377 0.00415 0.00333 0.0044 ...
```

Here is my code at the moment:

```
    # ========================= LOAD REQUIRED PACKAGES, DATA AND FUNCTIONS ####
#  load necessary packages
library('shiny')
library('ggplot2')
library('reshape2')
library("data.table")
library("dplyr")
library("vegan")
library("gdata")
#
library(shinyjs)
library(logging)
#
# library("stringr")
# load reference data
# none right now
# Load experimental data (abundance tables)
# first row is the header, and first column is rownames (ie. doesn't need corresponding column name)
f_genus<-read.table("b_Genus.csv",header=T,sep=",",row.names=1)
f_family<-read.table("b_Family.csv",header=T,sep=",",row.names=1)
f_phylum<-read.table("b_Phylum.csv",header=T,sep=",",row.names=1)
# read in bacterial data
bact_genus<-read.table("ss_Genus.csv",header=T,sep=",",row.names=1)
bact_family<-read.table("ss_Family.csv",header=T,sep=",",row.names=1)
bact_phylum<-read.table("ss_Phylum.csv",header=T,sep=",",row.names=1)
# sample metadata
sample_metadata<-read.csv("sample_metadata.csv",row.names=1,header=T)
##
abundance_tables<-list(fungi_genus=f_genus,fungi_family=f_family,fungi_phylum=f_phylum,
                       bact_genus=bact_genus,bact_family=bact_family,bact_phylum=bact_phylum)
## add diversity and species count columns to each abundance table
abundance_tables<-lapply(abundance_tables,function(tab) {tab$diversity<-diversity(tab) ; tab})
abundance_tables<-lapply(abundance_tables,function(tab){                           
                          tab$species_count<-apply(tab,1, function(x) {length(x[x>0])});tab})
##
FactorsOfInt<-c("Metarhizium","Insect","Sample_Type","Metarhizium*Insect","Metarhizium*Sample_Type")
# =========================  UI  ####
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Make a title to display in the app
  titlePanel(" Exploring the Effect of Metarhizium on the Soil and Root Microbiome "),
  # Make the Sidebar layout
  sidebarLayout(
    # Put in the sidebar all the input functions
    sidebarPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id="tabs",
        tabPanel("otu", selectInput('dataset', 'dataset', names(abundance_tables),selected=names(abundance_tables)[1]),
                 uiOutput("otu"), br(),
                 # Add comment
                 p("For details on OTU identification please refer to the original publications")),
        tabPanel("anova", sliderInput('pval','p-value for significance',
                                      value=0.1,min=0,max=0.5,step=0.00001),
                 selectInput('dataset', 'dataset', names(abundance_tables)),
                 selectInput('fact_ofInt','factor of interest',FactorsOfInt,selected="Metarhizium"))
        ) 
    ),
    # Put in the main panel of the layout the output functions 
      mainPanel(
        conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs == 'otu'",
                         plotOutput('plot'),
                            dataTableOutput("table")
        ),
        conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs == 'anova'",
                         #plotOutput('plot2')
                         verbatimTextOutput("anovaText")
                        # dataTableOutput("anova_tab2")

        )
      )
  )
)
# ========================= SERVER ####
  server <- function(input, output){
    # Return the requested dataset ----
    datasetInput <- reactive({
      abundance_tables[[input$dataset]]
    })
    pvalInput<-reactive({
      input$pval
   })
    comparisonInput<-reactive({
      input$FactorsOfInt
    })
    #
    # output otus to choose basaed on dataset selection
   output$otu <- renderUI({
     selectInput(inputId = "otu", label = "otu",
                       choices = colnames(datasetInput()),selected="Metarhizium")
    })
   otuInput<-reactive({
     input$otu
   })
   output$plot <- renderPlot({
     df<-datasetInput()
     otu<-otuInput()
     ## melt and add sample metadata
     df_annot<-merge(df,sample_metadata,by="row.names",all.x=T)
     rownames(df_annot)<-df_annot[,1]
     df_annot<-df_annot[,-1]
     #
     df_annot<-subset(df_annot,df_annot$Bean =="Bean")
     #
     dfM<-melt(df_annot,id.vars = c("Location","Bean","Fungi","Insect"),value.name="abund")
     # renaming Fungi level to metarhizium
     levels(dfM$Fungi)<-c("Metarhizium","No Meta")
     # subset based on otu of interest
     dfM.sub<-subset(dfM,dfM$variable==otu)
     # 
     ggplot(dfM.sub,aes(x=Insect,y=abund,fill=Fungi))+geom_boxplot()+
       facet_wrap(~Location,scales="free_y" )+
       guides(fill=guide_legend("Metarhizium")) +
       ggtitle(otu)
   })
     ## now make anova table
    output$table <- renderTable({
      df<-datasetInput()
       otu<-otuInput()
      print(paste("otu selected:",otu))
      ## melt and add sample metadata
      df_annot<-merge(df,sample_metadata,by="row.names",all.x=T)
      rownames(df_annot)<-df_annot[,1]
      df_annot<-df_annot[,-1]
      #
      df_annot<-subset(df_annot,df_annot$Bean =="Bean")
      df_annot<-drop.levels(df_annot)
      #
      dfM<-melt(df_annot,id.vars = c("Location","Bean","Fungi","Insect"),value.name="abund")
      # renaming Fungi level to metarhizium
     # levels(dfM$Fungi)<-c("Metarhizium","No Meta")
      # subset based on otu of interest
      dfM.sub<-subset(dfM,dfM$variable==otu)
      print(paste("dim dfM.sub: ",dim(dfM.sub)))
      aov.ex <- aov(dfM.sub$abund~dfM.sub$Fungi)
      anova_table<-as.data.frame(summary(aov.ex)[[1]])
     })
  #### if anova tab selected
  output$anovaText<-renderText({
    "anova Table"
  })


  })
   ### end of server
  }
  ##
 shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Does your ANOVA work outside your shiny app? That error usually means one of the variables in your model only has one level. Also why is your `output$table` embedded in `output$plot`

Comment: yes the ANOVA works outside of the shiny app.  I have also fixed, that table is not embedded in plot.  I've edited my new script, with a few new prints and doing things with reactive and trying to set defaults

Comment: It's difficult to figure out where the error is occurring without your data, though it might have something to do with the selected defaults for your datasets and factors. Can you provide a subset of your data that works in the app code you've provided?

Comment: Hi, not sure if this was the best way to provide a subset of my data, but I tried

Comment: @user2814482 Can you clarify what table you're looking for on the otu tab, under your plots versus what table you want on the anova tab? You've specified in your UI a couple different tables, but it's not clear what kind of table you want in which place.

Comment: sorry, in the code I posted, I deleted the function for the table in the anova tab, because I thought it was too much to debug at once.  In the otu tab, I want a table of an anova analysis of the abundance of specific otu versus a factor (right now I"ve simiplifed to just Fungi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue here is a mismatch between `dataTableOutput()` in the UI and `renderTable()` in the server. These always need to match; i.e., `tableOutput()` goes with `renderTable()` and `dataTableOutput()` goes with `renderDataTable()`.

Replace

```
conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs == 'otu'",
                     plotOutput('plot'),
                     dataTableOutput("table")
),
```

with

```
conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs == 'otu'",
                     plotOutput('plot'),
                     tableOutput("table")
),
```

And your anova table will show beneath your plot. **Alternatively**, you could replace

```
output$table <- renderTable({
...
})
```

with

```
output$table <- renderDataTable({
...
})
```

Either will get your table to show.

As for the errors you note, you're right that they are a response to not having anything in `input$otu` when the app loads. To avoid throwing errors until the app catches up, you can require that `input$otu` is populated before trying to plot the data or put in the table in the first line inside your `renderPlot()` and `renderTable()` calls:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
  req(is.null(input$otu)==F)
  ...
})
```

You'll note when the app loads that the same delay is there, but there are no errors.